# django rest framework: conditionally choosing serializer from same model

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

My model

#### formula.py

```
TYPE_CHOICES = [
    ('new',),
    ('existing',),
]

user = models.ForeignKey("users.User")
type = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=TYPE_CHOICES,
)
name = models.CharField(u"처방명", max_length=20)
reference = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
)
base_formula = models.CharField(
        max_length=40,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
)
```

#### formula_line.py

```
herb_item = models.ForeignKey("herbs")
formula = models.ForeignKey("formulas")
quantity = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

I want to serializer the model to be in the following form.

#### Output

```
# Use the type field to separate objects. Differently-typed objects include different fields

{
'new': {
            {
                'user': UserId1,
                'base_formula': string,
                'formula_id': int,
            },
            {
                'user': UserId2,
                'base_formula': string,
                'formula_id': int,
            },
            {
                'user': UserId3,
                'base_formula': string,
                'formula_id': int,
            },
        },

'existing': {
                {
                    'name': string,
                    'reference': string,
                    'formula_id': int,
                },
                {
                    'name': string,
                    'reference': string,
                    'formula_id': int,
                },
                {
                    'name': string,
                    'reference': string,
                    'formula_id': int,
                },
            }
}
```

I have been searching through SOF and reading the doc for some time, but I cannot find a way to do this.

I have the faintest idea that I probably should either:

1. override get_serializer_class somehow
2. override __init__

But I really cannot think of a way to implement this.

Please note that I thought about dividing the model into NewFormula and ExistingFormula, and use two different serializers accordingly. But this was not possible because I have Formula field in CartItem model that references Formula, meaning this approach might cause bit of a headache in that the same field references two different tables depending on condition.

Thanks for reading. Any ideas lad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to use a serializer that knows how to serialize *all* fields on the model.

I don't know why it would hurt to show an empty `base_formula` for existing fields.

But if you really want to show different fields based on the instance you are serializing (existing or new) that should be [doable](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields).

Something along these lines:

```
class FormulaModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Formula
        fields = [...]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FormulaModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.instance.formula_set:
            # hide the fields you don't want to show for an existing object
            self.fields.pop(user)
```